# Some redirects are translating incorrectly while most are working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, apache, redirect

Using Apache, MySQL, and PHP, and I'm noticing strange behaviors with URL redirects.

Our db entry is

```
src = 'pfe/pdf/03-b-06.pdf'
dst = 'https://site2.com/communities/policyprocedure/pfe/Active/03-b-06.pdf'
```

The redirect result translates correctly:

```
'http://site1.com/pfe/pdf/03-b-06.pdf'
```

Resolves to:

```
'https://site2.com/communities/policyprocedure/pfe/Active/03-b-06.pdf'
```

However, this one does not resolve correctly:

```
src = 'employee/jsp/common/generic.jsp?id=22910'
dst = 'https://site2.com/communities/policyprocedure/pfe/intranet-pages/22-urology'
```

Redirect translates as:

```
'http://site1.com/employee/jsp/common/generic.jsp?id=22910'
```

Resloves to:

```
'https://site2.com/communities/policyprocedure/pfe/intranet-pages/22.-urology'
```

We have thousands of URLs using numbers, and hyphens, and alpha characters  (i.e. /03-example) that work but only a dozen out of several thousand don't work.

Could it be something to do with the destination and its URL encoding? I have made sure it wasn't a character set or character encoding in the SQL insert/update strings.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `.` between `22` and `-urology` isn't being added by some redirect on the remote site?

Comment: Are you using PHP for rewriting the urls and redirecting? Could you put the code here, please?

Comment: PHP won't add a `.` by itself like that, it must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: thats was my suspicion, its going from a linux RHEL (apache) server to windows IIS sharepoint server. The only weird thing is if I enter the url directly to the browser it works.

I've used a variety of link verification tools and SEO tools to verify the full redirect path and I've tried  curl -I -l -v [url]  and it definitely is being altered in route.

i've looked at the redirect logs from my destination servers. I see it hit the access logs but because its being redirected in php thats where the path ends.

Answer (score 0):

index php:

```
<?php
// Pull in the database config
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/config.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/functions.php";

// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Get the requested URL
$src = htmlspecialchars($_GET['src']);

// Handle the empty src
if (empty($src)) {
  header('Location: ' . $at);
  exit;
}

// Open a DB connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Stop if the DB connection fails
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Query the database
$sql = "SELECT dst FROM map WHERE src = '" . $src . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();

// Act on the results
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!getResult($row['dst'])) {
      fourOhFourCapture($sp,$row['dst']);
    }
    header('Location: ' . $row['dst']);

  }
```

config .php:

```
<?php

$servername = 'servername';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'database';

$file = '/home/svc_account/404_results.txt';

$at = 'https://site1.cpm/';
$sp = 'https://site2.com/';
```

function php:

```
<?php

function urlExist($url)
{
  $handle = curl_init($url);

  if (false === $handle) {
    return false;
  }

  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") );
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
  $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
  curl_close($handle);
  return $connectable;
}

function fourOhFour($url,$req)
{
  header('Location: ' . $url . '?requestUrl=' . $req);
}

function fourOhFourCapture($url,$src)
{
  global $file;
   file_put_contents($file, $url.$src, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

/**
 * getResult - accepts a url, uses curl to check the status, and returns false if the code is 404, and true for any
 * other result
 * @param $url
 * @return bool
 */
function getResult($url) {

  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
  $response = curl_exec($handle);

  /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($handle);

  if($httpCode == 404) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
```

apache rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^$ https://site2.com/ [L]

  RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^/lbactive\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dept/department\.jsp [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/common/generic\.jsp
  RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI} [E=IS_LEGACY_OID:TRUE]

  RewriteMap legacy_oid_map txt:/var/vhost/site1/data/rewrites_legacy_oid.txt

  RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_LEGACY_OID} ^TRUE$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
  RewriteRule .* ${legacy_oid_map:%1}? [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^/site1/(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?src=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```